# Associating workitem category to team area in RTC

Tags: rtc

I could create WorkItem categories but getting an error while associating it to the teamarea.Getting error in the line createcategory.getAssociatedTeamAreas().add(newTAHandle). I am not getting how to return a boolean object of ITeamAreaHandle inside add method. Getting the compilation error : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Please help. Below is the related code.

```
IWorkItemClient wservice = (IWorkItemClient) teamRepository.getClientLibrary(IWorkItemClient.class);
ICategory createcategory = wservice.createCategory(area, categoryName, null);
wservice.saveCategory(createcat, null);

 if (!teamArea.equals("NULL")){
                   List teamAreas = area.getTeamAreas();
                   List <teamareahandle> teamlist = teamAreas;
                   ITeamAreaHandle newTAHandle = findTeamAreaByName(teamlist,teamAreaName,monitor);

              createcategory.getAssociatedTeamAreas().add(newTAHandle);
     }

//Method findTeamAreaByName

private static ITeamAreaHandle findTeamAreaByName (List<teamareahandle> teamlist, String teamAreaID, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws TeamRepositoryException {
            for (ITeamAreaHandle teamAreaHandle  :  teamlist) {
            ITeamArea teamArea = (ITeamArea)teamRepository.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(teamAreaHandle,ItemManager.DEFAULT,monitor);
            if (teamAreaID.equals(teamArea.getName())) {
                return teamAreaHandle;
                }
                }
                return null;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/33293/setting-associated-team-area-for-category?redirect=/forum/questions/33293/setting-associated-team-area-for-category) comments:

> **The API to associate categories with team areas is internal**.
>
> If you need it anyway, cast the `ICategory` to the internal `Category` interface and use e.g. `category.setDefaultTeamArea(...)`.
>
> You can set the associated ones using:

```
((Category) category).getTeamAreas().add(teamArea);
```

Comment: well I had tried this but this doesn't associate the team areas to categories. I thought of using this syntax :((Category)createcat).getAssociatedTeamAreas().add(teamArea); but it throws the same error as above.

Comment: @KaushambiSuyal ok, maybe it is related to the `newTAHandle` type? I mean: If you have to cast `ICategory` into `Category`, maybe a similar cast is in order to `ITeamAreaHandle` (into an internal type)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ICategory category = workItemClient.createCategory(projectArea, categoryName, getProgressMonitor());

((Category) category).doSetDefaultTeamArea(teamArea);
((Category) category).setArchived(false); //if it is archived

workItemClient.saveCategory(category, getProgressMonitor());
```